# What are these fungal growths in my gardens mulch?

Tags: fungi-identification, fungi

All over the mulch in my garden are these small brown fungus (I think it's a fungus?):

[image: fungus]

Some almost look like they "hatched" open, while others have a cap. What are these growths? They first appeared last year, but this year there are many more.

Comment: There are [several types of mushroom called "bird's nest fungus"](https://www.inaturalist.org/search?q=bird%20nest%20fungus) because they look like bird nests. I'm not an expert at mushroom identification so I can't narrow it down any further than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing the [link](https://www.inaturalist.org/search?q=bird%20nest%20fungus) posted in the comments by [csk](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/18576/csk), I looked into it and I believe that this is [*Cyathus striatus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyathus_striatus) or more commonly, *fluted bird's nest* fungus.

Pictures seen [here](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/fungus-lichen/birds-nest-fungus.htm) seem to be very similar if not identical to what I have in my garden, as well as some of the pictures in the link posted by csk.

[image]